# How to orchestrate members in a cluster to read new input from a single file once the current job is done?

Tags: file-io, fortran, mpi, fortran90

I am working on a global optimization using brutal force. I am wondering if it is possible to complete the following task with Fortran MPI file I/O:

I have three nodes, A, B, C. I want these nodes to search for the optima over six sets of parameter inputs, which are arranged in the following matrix:

```
0.1 0.2 0.3
0.4 0.5 0.6
0.7 0.8 0.9
1.1 1.2 1.3
1.4 1.5 1.6
1.7 1.8 1.9
```

A row vector represents a set of parameter inputs. The order of which node reading in which set of parameter inputs does not matter. All I need is to orchestrate nodes A, B, C to run through the six sets of parameters, obtain the corresponding value of penalty function, and save the output to a single file.

For example, node A pulls the first set, node B the second, and node C the third. Each node takes a while to finish respective computation. Since the computation time varies across nodes, it is possible that C is the first that finishes the first-round computation, and followed by B and then A. In such a case, I want node C to subsequently pull the forth set of inputs, node B to pull the fifth and node A to read in the last set.

```
A <--- 0.1 0.2 0.3
B <--- 0.4 0.5 0.6
C <--- 0.7 0.8 0.9
C <--- 1.1 1.2 1.3
B <--- 1.4 1.5 1.6
A <--- 1.7 1.8 1.9
```

What troubles me is that the order of which node to read which set for the second-round computation is not known in advance due to the uncertainty in the run time of respective node. So I would like to know if there is a way to dynamically program my code with MPI file I/O to attain such a parallel need. Can anyone show me a code template to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Lee

Comment: @High Performance Mark I have done the googling for the information I want. To my knowledge, there is not much material about MPI "File" I/O with advanced example circulating on the Internet. It would be much appreciated if you can let me know, for solving a problem I described, what MPI file i/o strategy/command you would use. Do you think it would be easier to have one node be in charge of the read-in-inputs function and then dynamically feed the inputs to other nodes?

Comment: Consider reading about hdf5, it's a data format that supports parallel IO and interfaces well with fortran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as it pains me to suggest it, this might be the one good use of MPI "Shared file pointers".   These work in fortran, too, but I'm going to get the syntax wrong.

Each process can read a row from the file with `MPI_File_read_shared` This independent I/O routine will update a global "shared file pointer" bit of state.  Should B or C finish their work quickly, they can call `MPI_File_read_shared` again.  If A is slow, whenver it calls `MPI_File_read_shared` it will read whatever has not been dealt with yet.

Some warnings:

- shared file pointers don't get a lot of attention.
- The global bit of shared state is typically... a hidden file.  So yeah, it might not scale terribly well.   Should be fine for a few tens of processes, though.
- the global bit of shared state is stored on a file system.  Some file systems like PVFS do not support the locking required to ensure this shared state is always correct.